# Temporary table in stored procedure syntax error

Tags: mysql, database

I'm trying to create a temporary table x based on a SELECT in my stored procedure in mysql in order to use it later on in the procedure but it gives me a syntax error on line 11 near 'SELECT * from x' and I'm not sure why.

```
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE x as
SELECT  concat(s.`Last name`,' ',s.`First name`),s.Gr_id,d.Disc_name,m.Mark
from teach_disc_groups tdg inner join marks m on tdg.teach_disc_groups_id=m.T_D_G_id
inner join students s on m.S_id=s.Stud_Id and tdg.G_id=s.Gr_id
inner join teach_discip td on tdg.T_D_id=td.teach_discip_id
inner join disciplines d on td.D_Id=d.Discipline_Id 
where td.T_Id=logid;

SELECT * from x
```

But if i execute the exact same code in the console of phpmyadmin it works without problems.Any ideas ?

p.s : logid is a parameter given in the stored procedure ,so that shouldn't give an error

Comment: You have set delimiters? And your select from x is not terminated

Comment: MySql does not use T-SQL... Based on the syntax I've removed the T-SQL tag.

Comment: I'm not entirely sure where should I put them , as far as I've read it is used to tell the mysql client that I've finished typing in an Sql statement.

Comment: please review https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/stored-programs-defining.html. Add the delimiter statements, the create procedure statement, and the begin and end statements for your procedure to the question.